# How to get vector representations(or embeddings) of time series?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, embeddings

Even if a time series is constructed up of numbers only, finding abstract fixed-dim vector representation would be interesting for classification/clustering purposes. As we can learn & find abstract representations/embeddings of text/images, can we do something similar on Time series? Finding such ways would result in better clustering & related tasks instead of traditional ways using some statistical measures like Pearson correlation etc. All thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Have you heard of time-series segmentation algorithms?  These seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: **Thanks @Edmund **, I hadn't heard that before; but now I have learned about it.This is similar to what I am looking for, but still not exact match.
 [A survey on TS segmentation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pazzani/Publications/survey.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the framework of Neural Processes could be interesting here? It defines a  family of functions parameterized by a neural network. The parameters could serve as your embeddings, eventually after projecting into a lower dimension. See the paper [Attentive Neural Processes](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SkE6PjC9KX) and the preceding papers cited therein.